# Ошибка при создании JSON файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

пытаюсь создать файл json,массив в начале, это который мне надо отсортировать и из него создать фай, но сначала для проверки пробую создать просто файл с одним текстом, но выходит такая ошибка не могу понять что за ошибка, искал решение, там было сказано что может стоять галочка только чтение, но ее нету поэтому не могу понять в чем проблема.[image: Пример кода].

[image: Пример Ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что в свойствах файла галочки не установлены[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не помогло, можете попробовать сменить путь к файлу или же запустить терминал изначально от имени администратора

Comment: Галочки не стоят,но спасибо, попробую через администратора,может получиться